# How do I use screen mirroring in iOS apps

Tags: ios, swift, screen, mirroring

I just need to use screen mirroring on enabled device when I click the button on my app screen. There is an airplay button in my app, clicking on which will check for available mirroring devices such as tv or laptop but I don't think it is for screen mirroring. I want to call screen mirroring in my app (I want to use mirroring not casting) on that screen.

[image: 1]

I don't know Objective-c well, so please use swift if you use example code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below, this might help you to understand how currently apps are achieving this.

[Screen Mirroring iPhone to smart TV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60264147/screen-mirroring-iphone-to-smart-tv)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let routePickerView = AVRoutePickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 30.0, width: 30.0, height: 30.0))
    routePickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    self.view.addSubview(routePickerView)

    let avAsset = AVAsset(url: URL(string: "https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4")!)
    let avPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset)
    let avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: avPlayerItem)
    let avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
    avPlayerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 40.0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height - 40.0)
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(avPlayerLayer)
    avPlayer.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
    avPlayer.play()
}
```

This code shows a player and adds the ability to mirror ONLY the player into the Mac screen.

You can check below as well.

[how-to-do-screen-mirroring-using-airplay-from-the-application-not-from-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23356127/how-to-do-screen-mirroring-using-airplay-from-the-application-not-from-control)

Comment: I meant screen mirroring not streaming. I think that is streaming.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204289
This site explains the difference between mirroring and streaming.
Thanks :)